# It is possible to paginate the categories??

Tags: categories, pagination

It is possible to paginate the categories??

Inside the site project there is a lot of categories, and i would paginate them. But i don't know if it's possible or not to paginate a categories list.

Thanks,

Stéphane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the category-related tags or add-ons have pagination that I am aware of.

But you could use the [Query module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/query/) or the [Active Record plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/activerecord) to generate your category listing. Both of these have pagination built in.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: It's very nice stackechange as community, sharing and solving the problems!!

Comment: It's working fine using Query module, It's easier that I imagined.